# How to write a timer to play video in bash?

Tags: bash, timer

It cost 50 minutes to play the video `debate.mkv`.

```
mplayer   debate.mkv
```

It play the  video `debate.mkv`

```
sleep  60
```

It make the os sleep for 1 minute.

I want to play the video for 1 minute ,then sleep 1 minute,go on to play the video at the previous break point for 1 minute ,then sleep 1 minute.

```
waitTime=60;
for i in {1..50} 
do
    startTime=$(date +%s)
    if [[ $(($(date +%s) - startTime))  -lt $waitTime ]];then
        mplayer   debate.mkv 
    else
        sleep  60
    fi
done
```

`mplayer   debate.mkv`  will not stop when  `$(($(date +%s) - startTime))`  is greater than  `$waitTime`,how to fix my bash code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your code can't control (start/stop) the `mplayer` command after it has been launched regardless of the mentioned `if` condition.
Try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

waitTime=60
mplayer debate.mkv &
pid=$!    # pid of mplayer above

for i in {1..50}
do
    sleep $waitTime
    kill -s SIGSTOP $pid
    sleep $waitTime
    kill -s SIGCONT $pid
done
```

Like other commands, `mplayer` accepts signals while working. The `SIGSTOP` signal pauses the execution and `SIGCONT` resumes it.